# How to hide/remove buttonclick animation

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, button, click

I wonder how you can disable the buttonclick animation from a windows forms button. What I mean is, when you click on the button, it doesnt look like its being pressed, it just stays solid.

I dont want to change it to

```
button1.enabled = false;
```

as I still want it clickable and with colour.

Hope you understand what I am asking for, I searched through the properties of the button but I didnt find anything that seemed to work, maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

You must look into following:

1. FlatStyle property of button
2. Apply appropriate image for the button

After setting FlatStyle property, you can control appearance on mouse-over and mouse-down by looking into **FlatAppearance** property.

[image: Example button properties using VS2008 .Net 3.5]